# What is the idiomatic way of making a String from two Int in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, scala-2.8

```
"" + int1 + int2
```

works, but it's a bit ugly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd probably go with `int1.toString + int2.toString` but that's just how I roll.

Comment: Thanks. Obvious, but somehow I'd missed it.

Comment: @Paul dw, you've put it out there now.  AND you've learned that you can sometimes miss the obvious:P

Answer (score 5):

Arguably uglier

```
"%d%d".format(int1, int2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is

```
Array(int1, int2).mkString
```

... also allows you this

```
Array(int1, int2).mkString(", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

The Scala developers did hard work do emulate this weird piece of Java compatibility, so I would probably just use what you suggested.

Comment: @Nicolas It was a joke (or at least that's how I took it) related to this thread: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.user/33893

Comment: Hum... a kinda private joke that can lead someone to bad practices is not adequate here I think especially if no reference are given to understand that this is a joke.

Comment: I'd agree if it were an objectively bad practice, but in this case it's just a stylistic preference. @soc just shared what _he_ would use.